# What is the main usage of Java NIO Buffer classes?

Tags: java, design-patterns, buffer, nio

I don't understand, what that Buffer classes are for. Aren't they for buffering? I think this should mean that one buffer object should allow both read and write it simultaneously and independently. Nevertheless it is not so: buffer allows only one `position`, single one for reading and writing. This means that if I wrote something into the buffer with relative `put()` then I can't read anything sensitive with relative `get()`. Also if I will call `put()` and `get()` interchangeably I will get a delirium.

So are there any usage patterns (samples) for buffers? So that it would be evident that those buffers are somehow better than conventional arrays?

Comment: I agree. It seems to me that the design is badly flawed in not having separate read and write pointers. The ugly name of the 'flip()' operation they provided instead kind of gives the game away too. If it had corresponded to something in the real world, it would have had a better name. Instead of which, it is entirely an API artifact, with an equally artificial name.

Answer (score 2):

ByteBuffer are used for read and writing data, you can get/put many primitive type and control the endianess. They can be a wrapper for direct memory (off heap) and memory mapped files (also off heap)

They can be used for performance (as they can access a long or double natively without assembling bytes together), direct byte buffers can read/write data without an additional copy into "Java" memory.  memory mapped files can be extended to the size of your disk space, allowing you to use lots of memory without impacting your GC times.

Comment: Is it possible to share the same array or memory region with two `ByteBuffers`? This would allow to use one for read and another for write?

Comment: What is exactly what I do to pass data between threads and processes. i.e. shared memory.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to create a ByteBuffer and splice(0 it.  Then you have two ByteBuffers using the same underlying buffer.

Comment: But why an array is not enough to be as a buffer(besides direct byte buffer), why a new class is designed to wrap the data. I ask a question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729953/why-java-nio-introduces-buffer-class-specially-rather-than-using-array