# Why Java NIO introduces Buffer class specially rather than using array?

Tags: java, io, buffer, nio

I was asked a question that why a byte array is not enough and NIO specially introduces a class `Buffer`?

What will be a good answer to this question? Is it only a kind of wrapper class which simplifies the read/write operation ?

If possible, please give us an example to demonstrate how we benefit from  `Buffer` class which can not/hardly be done with an array.

Comment: DMA with bytebuffer which might not be possible with byte array see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#direct) fro byte buffers

Comment: Java arrays aren't dynamically resizable, and they have a fixed length. Of course, that is what we call a (educated) guess.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, would you please show us an example that how Buffer is used its functionality of non-fixed length that array is not enough to do at the answer?

Comment: @Jaskey No, because there is no such example possible. Obviously everything *could* have been done with an array, but Java's designers *chose* to implement `ByteBuffer`... your question was why they did that, and the answer (since I didn't do it) must be a guess.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , well, sure most of us cannot know the reasons, while there must be some obvious advantage for this design, so I think the example for this advantage is enough to be a fine answer.

Comment: @Jaskey Why do you think there is [`ByteBuffer.hasArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#hasArray%28%29)? Hint, the `ByteBuffer` could be backed by something else.

Comment: @Jaskey What don't you understand about ['There is one subclass of this class for each non-boolean primitive type'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html)?